# knockout.js value binding triggered by unusual keys in version 2.2.0

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

Consider the following trivial example:

```
<input data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
```

In knockoutjs 2.1.0, when I press any of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Up arrow</kbd>,<kbd>Down arrow</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd> the binding is ***not*** fired and `query` is not updated.

In knockoutjs 2.2.0, the binding fires for all the above keypresses.

This is playing havoc with some existing code (it's an autocomplete, and arrow up and down are frequently used to select from the drop down).

Which behaviour is correct? I assume technically, the latter is correct as these pressing these keys **is** a keydown event, but shouldn't the binding only fire if the value has changed?

I want to keep everything real-time, and the [docs state](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html):

> "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to keep your view model updated in real-time

Suggestions?

- ko 2.1.0 demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmcza/7/
- ko 2.2.0 demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rmcza/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a result of [this change](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/commit/4fe4f0fc1313e82cf84e031e2e8412631d51a256) made by RP Niemeyer in Sept. It causes computed observables to always write when triggered, even if the value hasn't changed.

You will notice in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rmcza/10/) that this does *not* occur when using a non-computed observable. I tested this using an explicit subscription, and the event does not fire for the down arrow.

```
this.test = ko.observable('');
this.test.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The test value new name is " + newValue);
});
```

Maybe Ryan can explain why this was changed, and why computed's are behaving differently than regular observables in this case. You might want to make an issue on the GitHub page.

Comment: The behavior in 2.1 was really unintended.  Here is the same fiddle with 2.0: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/4FDKC/. My suggestion would be to use an observable with a subscription as described by @Tyrsius. Computeds often run logic within the write function that needs to happen whenever the binding is triggered.  This caused an issue with several cases like the one described here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/562

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Um. A write occurs for me when I press down.

Comment: Can you clarify?  In which version? With the computed or manual subscription?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer In the fiddle you posted for 2.0. This one: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/4FDKC/. Using Chrome if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks both. That's all the info I need to proceed.

Comment: My point was that 2.0 and 2.2 behave the same and 2.1 had unintended behavior. Am I understanding your comment correctly?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer Right, that makes more sense. I was confused. I thought you were saying 2.0 didn't do that. Ignore me.

Comment: I've added my own answer here that represents the least intrusive method I could find to get back the 2.1 behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the `subscribe` method suggested above, but it seemed a little messy and not in the spirit of knockout. A colleague suggested writing an extender that would suppress the binding in the case of no change (which would emulate the 2.1 behaviour):

```
ko.extenders.suppressNoChange= function(target) {
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target();
            if (newValue!== current) {
                target(newValue);
            }
        }
    });
    result(target());
    return result;
};
```

so now we can extend our computed observables such that the binding will not fire in the case where no change has occurred.

We can use it as follows:

```
ko
  .computed({
     read: function(){},
     write: function(v){})
  .extend({
     suppressNoChange: null
  });
```

and allows me to make very minimal changes to the 2.2 fiddle in the question to restore the 2.1 behaviour.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Rmcza/26/